# How do I properly calculate the curl of the Aharonov-Bohm flux line vector potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Given a vector potential describing an infinitely thin line of flux,

$$\vec{A} = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi r} \vec{e}_\varphi,$$

How can I calculate the curl so that the magnetic field is given by

$$\vec{B} = \delta(x) \delta(y) \Phi \vec{e}_z,$$

or similar expression? The expression for the curl (in cylindrical coordinates) comes down to this:

$$\nabla \times \vec{A} = \vec{e}_z \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r A_\varphi).$$

I am aware there is a singularity at $r=0$ which will probably give me the answer. I just don't see how. I'm asking here, because well, a mathematician might get a fit caused by my liberal use of Dirac delta's above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the 2-dimensional Green's function for the Laplacian to find an alternative representation of the 2-dimensional delta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of my comment: Recall
$$\Delta\log r=2\pi\delta^2(x,y)$$
On the right we have $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial\log r}{\partial r}\right)$$
Your potential can be written as
$$\vec A=\frac{\Phi}{2\pi}\frac{\partial\log r}{\partial r}\vec e_\varphi$$
The curl is then
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec A=\frac{\Phi}{2\pi}\frac{1}{r}\left(r\frac{\partial\log r}{\partial r}\right)\vec e_z=\frac{\Phi}{2\pi}\Delta\log r\,\vec e_z=\delta^2(x,y)\Phi\vec e_z$$
As was to be shown.

Comment: Right, and where does the naive approach (i.e. filling in the curl directly) actually go wrong? I'm still unable to pinpoint exactly which step is illegal/wrong and how to perform that step generically in a mathematically correct way. Thanks.

Comment: @rubenvb: Filling in the curl directly?

Comment: $\nabla \times \boldsymbol A =  \frac{1}{r} \partial_r r \frac{\Phi}{2\pi r} = \frac{\Phi}{2\pi r} \partial_r 1 = 0$. Or something like that.

Comment: Of course that is only the $\boldsymbol e_z$ part, the rest is identically zero.

Comment: @rubenvb: The fraction $\frac{1}{r}\partial_r 1$ is not well defined at $r=0$. It is the "peak" of the delta function, which is clear from the identity $\Delta\log r=2\pi\delta^2(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account that your vector potential is defined only for $r >0$. For $r=0$, the vector potential actually vanishes, $\vec{A}(0) = \vec{0}$. You can show this by considering a thick solenoid and letting its width go to zero. Therefore, the correct expression for the vector potential of a thin solenoid is $$\vec{A} = \theta(r) \frac{\Phi}{2\pi r} \vec{e}_\varphi.$$ Here, $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside step function. This will give you a correct magnetic field which is proportional to a delta function.